# Intermittent ding/sonar sound coming from Macbook Pro... even when turned off!

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

My MacBook Pro late 2014 is making a ping sonar-like noise every 30-35 seconds, **even when muted and the laptop is turned off.** It seems to be coming from the left side of the MacBook and is very loud.

I've made a [video](https://youtu.be/K5agpvskbNI) so you can hear the sound and how frequently it occurs (first noise at 0:14, then 0:53 and finally 1:31).

Answer (score 1):

There is an alert noise when logic board is failing/has failed.

Have you tried various start-up options?